Как сделать бота на telebot работающего с aiosqlite и telebot асинхронным
Я имею бота использовавшего библиотеки sqlite3 и telebot, в нём множество взаимосвязанных функций во многих из которых есть запросы к БД, мне захотелось переделать бота под ассинхронизацию для отсутствия ошибок при работе с большим кол-во пользователей. Добавил библиотеку aiosqlite, перед всеми запросами в бд использовал await а перед функциями поставил async, но в при первом же запросе /start возникает ошибка RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'starts' was never awaited task(*args, **kwargs) подскажите пожалуйста с этой и последующими подобными ошибками
import telebot;
import sqlite3
import aiosqlite
import random
import asyncio
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('');
conn = aiosqlite.connect("", check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def starts(message):
*код и еще множество других функций


https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#asynchronous-telebot
